# Wix website: How to have a section of a profile (user ID) page collapsed, until the user checks a checkbox on their "update profile" page?

Tags: checkbox, expand

When a user signs up, multiple pages are created (because of how I'm working with Wix Dynamic pages and their Content Management System). Among those pages are the **public profile page** and the private **update profile info** page.

How do I keep a **section** of the public profile page **collapsed** until the user decides to **check a checkbox** on the "update profile info" page?

I've already managed to set the default value of the **section** as collapsed. It was an option that didn't require code.

I'm new to coding, btw, but not a complete noob.

I don't know exactly how to get **checking the checkbox** to expand the collapsed **section**.

And in this case, **section** and **checkbox** are on two different pages, which complicates things even further.

I hope you guys have some ideas and I appreciate any time you take to look into this.